# how to fix anaconda that shows error after installation?

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to install anaconda on my ubuntu 18.04 using the anaconda documentation. It shows the installation is complete.

But when I try to do anaconda-navigator it shows "command not found" error.

When I go to the base by using source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root, the prompt starts with (base) and it will load the anaconda with some error in the terminal as follows

```
/home/roshni/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator     /api/conda_api.py:1364: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
data = yaml.load(f)
2019-07-27 12:28:50,326 - ERROR download_api._download:234
Invalid url https://www.anaconda.com…/Webinar20-20Three20Ways20to20Mov…
```

don't know what's wrong. I once installed anaconda in windows without any issues.

Also, won't this anaconda create an icon on the desktop or in the application list? I can't find one in the application list. how to open it and start working with it each time.?

I am new to this and love to learn. Hope someone here can help me.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part *"**YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated**"* is not an error, just a warning, and as it's in this case it would not prevent the action to be completed. The message say "is deprecated".

On the link https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation they explain this and how to disable the warning.

> PyYAML's load function has been unsafe since the first release in May 2006. It has always been documented that way in bold type: PyYAMLDocumentation. PyYAML has always provided a safe_load function that can load a subset of YAML without exploit.
>
> Last year a CVE was filed against PyYAML because it was capable of being exploited on untrusted input using the load function, even though PyYAML was intentionally designed and documented to work that way from the start. The CVE seems to suggest that load should use safe_load by default. Since safe_load only handles a subset of YAML, and PyYAML has been a very popular Python package for over a decade, this change is not feasible.

On the second part *"**ERROR download_api._download:234**"* just mean you won't see some of the content you see on the Community. In this case would be the url of the error. But the Navigator operation should not be affected.

They are aware of the error and working on it, as they explain here https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10711

> "The error is not on the Navigator side, it is on the www.anaconda.com side - and we are aware and working to fix it."